# Can I connect VScode and Intellij to the same gitlab account?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, gitlab, ide

I am using two of them recently from my local computer.
my Gitlab is currently connected to the intellij
but I am also using Visual Studio Code and I wonder if it is possible to connect the visual studio code too.
Thank you so much

I tried to search but cant find

Comment: yes - should be. did you try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, [Visual Studio 2012](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Studio#History) is not the same as [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/).

Second, as long as your [Git for Windows](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases) works from command line (meaning you can `git clone/push/pull`):

- either using an HTTPS URL (with the [GCM -- Git Credential Manager](https://github.com/GitCredentialManager/git-credential-manager) -- packaged with Git For Windows, taking care of caching the username/[token](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/profile/personal_access_tokens.html) credentials)
- or using an SSH URL (with the [public key registered to your GitLab user SSH setting page](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/ssh.html#add-an-ssh-key-to-your-gitlab-account))

Then both Visual Studio (or VSCode), like IntelliJ IDEA will pick up those same URLs, and use through Git the same HTTPS credentials or SSH keys as command-line.